# How do I convert an email body to plain text in python?

Tags: python, email

I'm trying to store the text from the body of an email into a file (as plain text) for comparison. This the section of the code that's currently giving me the problem:

```
result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")
ids = data[0]
id_list = ids.split()
latest_email_id = id_list[-1]

result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")
raw_email = data[0][1]
mymail = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)


mytext=mymail.get_payload()[0].get_payload()
print(mytext)
```

The output of the file looks like this:

email.message.Message object at 0x03BFC410>, email.message.Message object at 0x03C0D210>

How do I get the body of the email as plain text?

Comment: There's at least a part of the output missing.

Comment: Read the [docs on `email.message.Message`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message).